# Listen for other application events on rooted device

Tags: android, root

Is it possible to listen for events (buttons clicks, typing in EditText, etc.) which happen in other Android applications on a rooted device?

Answer (score -1):

Nope, why shouldn't it? It makes no difference whether you have a root device or not. Probably you could write a system wide app that is kind of overlay over the whole screen (above running apps) to intercept touch events, so that you know that the user has touched on location X/Y on screen, but as far as I know there is no way to know which UI element is beyond this coordinates on the screen.

Comment: I read about creating such type of overlay, but even if this type of behaviour was possible on older devices, it isn't possible anymore.